# How to calculate the moist adiabatic lapse rate?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, thermodynamics

I'm trying to calculate the saturated moist adiabatic lapse rate with the following formula:

$L_m = \frac{y_d}{1+\frac{L_v}{c_p}\frac{d_q(s)}{dT}}$

with:

- $y_d = 9.8 (K\ km^{-1})\\\\$,
- $L_v = 2.5*10^6 (J\ kg^{-1})\\\\$,
- $c_p = 1004 (J\ kg^{-1} K^{-1})\\\\$,
- $T$ = temperature $(K)\\\\$,
- $q(s)$ = saturation specific humidity $(kg/kg)\\\\$

Imagine air at a pressure level of 760 hPa that has a temperature of 4 degrees Celsius. If I fill in the formula:

First calculate the saturation specific humidity for 2 temperatures:

$qs_1$ for $T_1$ (3°C) = 0.622*((6.11*exp(19.85 - 5423/(273.15+3))*100))/(76000) * 1000
= 6.18 g/kg = 0.006180 kg/kg

$qs_2$ for $T_2$ (5°C) = 0.622*((6.11*exp(19.85 - 5423/(273.15+5))*100))/(76000) * 1000
= 7.12 g/kg = 0.007120 kg/kg

Fill in the formula:

$L_m = \frac{0.0098}{1+\frac{2.5*10^6}{1004}\frac{0.007120-0.006180}{5-3}} = 8.34480 \ K\ km^{-1}$

This seems rather high. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @gansub according to this calculator (http://kishou.u-gakugei.ac.jp/tools/calc/gammaw.html) the answer should be 5.44 K km-1. I don't know how to get to that result. I'd prefer to be able to understand and calculate it myself rather then using pre-existing packages.

Comment: @gansub thank you for your answers! I found that equation in Wallace and Hobbs (2006) chapter 3: atmospheric thermodynamics, p. 107 (the equation with the blue square to the right of it, see https://gibbs.science/teaching/efd/handouts/wallace_hobbs_ch3.pdf)